# Looping until cell is empty and implementing "if" function for web automation using Python and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, vba, selenium, csv, for-loop

I'm kind of new to web automation and I'm having an issue with being able to loop through the cells in a csv column until they're empty then to exit the loop and continue on.

My code structure has a loop and I was wondering if putting a loop inside of the loop would do the trick? If so I'm unaware of how to add this loop or how to structure it. So any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code below.

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

for line in csv_reader:

    driver.get('www.websiteurl.com')

    time.sleep(3)

    # Input of Proband Indications from the CSV file from column 5.
    proband_indications = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-cmp/div/app-secured/app-case-create/div/form/div[2]/app-case-subject/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/app-autocomplete/div/div/div/input')
    proband_indications.clear()
    proband_indications.send_keys(line[5])
    time.sleep(2)

    proband_indications_selection = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/mat-option[1]')[0]
    proband_indications_selection.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    # Submit analysis button click
    submit_analysis_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/app-cmp/div/app-secured/app-case-create/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/button[3]')[0]
    submit_analysis_button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why do you need selenium? You're opening a file available on your local machine. No need to use it.

Comment: What's the actual problem here? Code looks like it would loop through the csv and do some browser interactions.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I need the bot to fill in a form starting from the 5th columns cell then continue filling in the form until the next cell in line is empty. The form is the type of form where you type in a name then click the option if there is a match then can type the next name and click the option, etc.

Comment: @DMart The issue I'm having is that I need the bot to fill in a form starting from the 5th columns cell then continue filling in the form until the next cell in line is empty. The form is the type of form where you type in a name then click the option if there is a match then can type the next name and click the option, etc.